# Related to Wearing the Underwear

Tags: tafseer

Assalamualaikum
I want to know that wearing underwear is good or bad for mens in Islam.
Some are telling that if you not wear Underwear You will face problems in main part and You will face problems after Marriage.
What should I do because I don't wear Underwear because I don't feel comfortable.

Comment: Wearing underwear is neither good nor bad in Islam.